# The realistic expectations from the Golden Calf

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-ki-tisa, golden-calf-egel

It is difficult for me to understand people's expectations from the Golden Calf they made.

Strangely Aharon and others didn't try to argue on the logic of creating a dummy. So the calf was magically created - then what?

How will it take leadership? How will it communicate with G-d? How will it provide the nation with supplies and shelter and everything they need? And the most important - **how will it replace Moses**?

I don't expect those people (אם הראשונים כמלאכים) to be plain stupid as Avraham proved the idolaters wrong by making fun of the idols.

So what did the Israelites expect from that Calf they created?

Comment: Only the Erev Rav worshipped it. Arguably, the whole “let’s replace Moshe” bit was an excuse to worship AZ.

Comment: @DonielF As I said, I don't accept this "they were all fouls" approach. There were 600K grown-up Jews. Oversimplifying will not get us any closer to understanding this incident.

Comment: That’s the point, we’re not referring to the 600K grown-up Jews; they didn’t sin. The Erev Rav were historically idolaters, and they slid back into their idolatry.

Comment: @DonielF How do you picture it. Pretend those are nowadays Israelis - so a bunch of Palestinians come across and demand from the Prime Minister to make a move to self-destroy the nation, and he willingly agrees. Does it sound realistic to you?

Comment: Aharon didn’t do it willingly - they had already killed Chur, and were they to kill him they’d “kill a Navi and a Kohen on one day.” In any event, what bearing does that have on the question at hand?

Comment: @DonielF so all the Jews were punished because of them? how many Erev Rav were there?

Comment: @larry909 Not sure on the exact number. But that’s the idea of כל ישראל ערבים זה לזה - if a Jew sees another Jew doing something wrong, is able to do something about it, and does nothing, he’s punished as well.

Comment: @DonielF so why is it part of the torah? Were the erev rav bona-fide Jews?

Comment: @larry Why shouldn’t they have been bona fide Jews? And why should it not be in the Torah - after all, we learn many lessons from it!

Comment: @DonielF I've read that they were insincere in their conversion. They only wanted to join the jews when they saw the miracles.

Comment: @larry So? After the fact we still accept them.